# importing esri-loader into nativescript

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, arcgis-js-api, esri-loader

i'm trying to import esri-loader into my nativescript vue app and show a simple map and am getting an error.  below is my code

```
<script>
import * as esriLoader from 'esri-loader'

export default {
  name: 'myMap',
  mounted: function () {
    esriLoader.loadModules(['esri/map'])
      .then(([Map]) => {
        // create map with the given options
        const map = new Map(this.$refs.map, {
          center: [-56.049, 38.485],
          zoom: 3,
          basemap: 'gray',
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // handle any script or module loading errors
        console.error(err);
      });
  }
}
</script>
```

and my error is below

```
JavaScript error:
file:///app/vendor.js:173:29: JS ERROR ReferenceError: Can't find variable: window
(CoreFoundation) *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript 
encountered a fatal error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: window
```

Has anyone successfully loaded esri-loader and a map in native script?

Comment: I haven't used `esri-loader` personally but you will not be able to use any library that depends browser specific features within NativeScript environment. Still creating a window object on global level might bypass this issue `global.window = {};`.

Comment: yes, i'm not even sure if it is possible, which i'm thinking may not be.

Answer (score 1):

**NO**, It can't be used in nativescript app as it has dependency on browser. This library doesn't have any external dependencies, but the functions it exposes to load the ArcGIS API and its modules expect to be run in a browser.

Although you can run away from the 'window not find' error by declaring that as global but esri will not render the map it looks for browser element and promises.

But you can use this library in other applications that are rendered on the server. For reference you can visit [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esri-loader#dependencies).